# Azure AD: Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal is failing with "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-service-principal

I am trying to create a "service principal" for application and to grant admin consent for the permissions using Microsoft graph API.

I followed the following steps:

1. Created application in a tenant using graph API. My request body is:

   ```json
   {
     "displayName": "AppWithPermissions",
     "requiredResourceAccess": [
       {
         "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
         "resourceAccess": [
           {
             "id": "dc890d15-9560-4a4c-9b7f-a736ec74ec40",
             "type": "Role"
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Created a service principal for the above-created application. The creation was successful.
3. Now, I want to grant admin consent to each assigned permission programmatically using graph API.
4. To grant application permissions, I created an app role assignment in the appRoleAssignedTo collection of the API's service principal:
   The request was as follows:

   Post request:

   ```
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo
   ```

   Request body:

   ```json
   {
       "principalId": "principal_id",
       "resourceId": "resource_id",
       "appRoleId": "approle_id"
   }
   ```

Here,

1. "principal_id" is the "id" of service principal created in step 2 above.
2. "approle_id" is the id of the appRole you want to grant. (taken "id" value from "resourceAccess" array present in "requiredResourceAccess")
3. "id" in http request url and "resource_id" are the same. (taken "resourceAppId" value from "requiredResourceAccess" which is corresponds to "approle_id" given above)

After running the query, I am getting error 404.
"code": "Request_ResourceNotFound"
for the "resource_id"/"id" field.

- Adding screenshots for better understandings:

1. App Creation:

[image]

2. service principal creation:

[image]

3. Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal:

[image]

I am confused about which IDs to use where and didn't get a clear idea from the documentations. Can any one please resolve my query? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the **appId** instead of the **id** value.

In an app role assignment, `resourceId` is the **id** of the **servicePrincipal** for the resource app (in your case, the API). In an **application** object's **requiredResourceAccess**, you use **appId**, which is a different value.

To find the **id** of a service principal for which you know the **appId**:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '{app-id}'
```

The response will contain the **id** property of the **servicePrincipal** object, and you can use that when creating the app role assignment.

Comment: Thanks Philippe. Let me clear my understanding, {resourceId}, {principalId} are same as the id property of the servicePrincipal object. But i still did not get what should be value of {appRoleId}? In my reponse of servicePrincipal object, 'appRoles' array is NULL. It is not related to values present in 'requiredResourceAccess' array?

Comment: If you retrieve the `servicePrincipal` for the API (e.g.`GET .../servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'`) the result will have an `appRoles` property which will have all the app roles defined for that API. However, in your case, you seem to already know the {appRoleId} values (e.g. 5b567255-7703-4780-807c-7be8301ae99b, 75359482-378d-4052-8f01-80520e7db3cd, etc.), so you can just use that directly.

Comment: I cannot use those values  (e.g. 5b567255-7703-4780-807c-7be8301ae99b, 75359482-378d-4052-8f01-80520e7db3cd, etc.) for {appRoleId}. I am getting this error: "message": "Permission being assigned was not found on application". We need to define "appRoles" array for application while creating.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the query you are making to create the app role assignment (include the body)?

Comment: i have updated my question with the steps and screenshot. Please refer them.

Comment: You are using the same value for `principalId` and resourceId`. To find `resourceId`, you need to look up the `id` of the servicePrincipal which has `appId` `00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000`. My answer here shows you how to do that. That's the value you need to use as `resourceId`.

Answer (score -2):

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) description is not very clear.

In simple terms:

`principalId`: Usually your service principal id.

`resourceId`: Usually your service principal id.

`appRoleId`: For appRoleId you can find it by requesting `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}.`
[image]

Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Carl for your response. In my case "appRoles": [] array is NULL. Did you performed any extra step while creating service principal? I have one more query: we don't fetch "appRoleId" from "requiredResourceAccess" array elements?

Comment: @PoojaDabhade  You can find it in the application manifest, go to Azure ad> App registrations>your app>Manifest  see:https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH4el.png

Comment: I also did the same thing, but getting error as shown in screenshots attached: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Umn69TJRbIVTfw1wWdfGYx43Sq_0ImY/view?usp=sharing  and  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hyDMLogihroII0N1LlezHn1g-yHl7oA0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @PoojaDabhade  Try to use a custom appRoleId https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGIzl.png, you can customize the appRoles by customizing the manifest in AD, go to Azure ad>App registrations>your app>Manifest to find appRoles and customize it,see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#examples

Comment: i tried that too. But now facing another issue as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330114/azure-service-principal-grant-an-approleassignment-for-a-service-principal-does