# Azure service principal: Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal does update the original permission's status

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-service-principal

I am trying to grant admin consent to assigned permissions using Microsoft graph APIs.
Steps i performed are as follows:

1. Create application having "appRoles" array defined.
2. create service principal with appId.
3. Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal.
   I ran http post request:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/%7Bid%7D/appRoleAssignedTo)

4. In Azure portal, instead of granting originally present permission, i see it is creating another permission and granting consent to it as displayed in the picture below.

[image]

Why it is not granting original permission, even though the 'appRoleId' is same? I want to grant original permission, can some one tell me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it will not grant the original permission, when you create an application and expose the API permission, this permission and the permission in `Exchange` are totally two different permissions from different APIs, no matter what the `appRoleId` they used.

To grant the `full_access_as_app` *Application permission* for your app, please follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to your AD App in the portal -> `Manifest` -> `requiredResourceAccess`, get the `resourceAppId` and `id`, note the `id` down as `appRoleId`.

[image]

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Enterprise applications` -> search for the `resourceAppId` got in step 1, then you will find the `Office 365 Exchange Online` -> click it -> `Overview`-> get the `Object ID`, note it down as `resourceId`.

**Note**: This `Object ID` is different in different AAD tenants.

[image]

3.Navigate to your AD App -> click the `Managed application in local directory`, then get the `Object ID`, note it down as `principalId`.

[image]

[image]

4.Then call the Microsoft Graph you used - [Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), use the values got before.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<resourceId>/appRoleAssignedTo

{
  "principalId": "<principalId>",
  "resourceId": "<resourceId>",
  "appRoleId": "<appRoleId>"
}
```

I test it in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#):

[image]

Check the result in the portal, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy, while performing step 2, i am getting error as shown: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fV8IDMFN-iwo0nHTSsDSeNDZEkse-y0F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @PoojaDabhade You need to specify the filter `Application type` with `Microsoft Applications`, not `Enterprise Applications`, see my screenshot.

Comment: Joy, this was helpful and i am able to grant the original permission with your answer. Thanks. I have one more query, is there any graph API present to get "ObjectId" of microsoft's application having "resourceId"?

Comment: @PoojaDabhade I don't know what actually you want, in this case, the `ObjectId` is the `resourceId` as mentioned in step 2, so if you know the `resourceId`, why you need to get it again?

Comment: My question was, how to retrieve "resourceId" having "resourceAppId" using Microsoft graph API. I found the query: GET .../servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' to fetch it.