# Azure Active Directory appRoleAssignments "Permission being assigned was not found on application"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to assign a user to the azure active directory application through graph API.
As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) I have assigned the permission to my application and granted the admin consent.
The following permissions are given to the application.

[image]
My graph API  requests details ares

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id/appRoleAssignments
```

Request Body

```
{
    "appRoleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "principalId": "user-id",
    "principalType": "User",
    "resourceId": "objectId-of-service-principal"
}
```

The response from AD API still mentioning **Permission being assigned was not found on application**
what other permissions do I need to give to the application to make the request work properly?

Comment: Have you added all the permissions mentioned here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: yes! @JagratiModi

Comment: The call needs to be something like this `/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignments` according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request).

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330114/azure-service-principal-grant-an-approleassignment-for-a-service-principal-does

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: I found the issue as I was giving an empty Role Id i.e "appRoleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" https://stackoverflow.com/a/43504909/3315744.
Finally I created an app role and gave the app role id in the request and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, it was caused by the wrong `appRoleId` you provided, the `appRoleId` should be the `id` of the appRole (defined on the resource service principal) to assign to the user, if you have not defined it, please follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) to denfine it.

[image]

To find `appRoleId`, navigate to `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations`
->  find the AD App you defined the appRole -> `Manifest` -> `appRoles` -> get the `id` like below, it is the `appRoleId`.

[image]

Then test the API with it again, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @joy_wang.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue but in my case, it's not related to appRoleId it is because of resourceId. I am using object ID as resourceId from App registrations itself, we need to get the object Id of the application from enterprise applications

```
Enterprise Applications -> Your Application where App role is defined -> overview -> ObjectId
```